# What is document.hrefFm in submitForm(document.hrefFm, someURL)?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In liferay, I found that we can call the portlet action url in javascript by

> submitForm(document.hrefFm, someActionURL);

I found some help on [submitForm(document.hrefFm, someURL)](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4723147) Forum but still not yet cleared with the concept.

With above script one can call his desired actions directly instead of using form and then submitting that form to perform action.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful when you need to execute a portlet action outside of a form, for example by clicking a `liferay-ui:icon` somewhere in your portlet pages or in the *Actions* menu of a Search Container.

Comment: What about the submitForm() function....Is it the default fuction to submit the form or define somewhere in liferay?

Comment: Yes, it does a couple of nice things, such as automatically disabling form buttons to prevent duplicated submits and firing a YUI3 event, which some Javascript widgets (`A.AutoFields`, for example) will use in order to populate a hidden input with their internal data before submit. In Liferay 6.1.1 (the latest CE version), this function is defined in js/util.js